# How to create this Crumpled Paper Transition for use in vse?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

How to create this Crumpled Paper Transitions for use in vse?

https://motionarray.com/premiere-pro-presets/crumpled-paper-transitions-223450/

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hi @Duarte Farrajota Ramos, thank you for your comment. I really had no idea how to start creating this effect in a form of a transition in the VSE, that's why I thought it is more suitable to link to a video that will show what I am looking 
to achieve. Hope I can update my question with a GIF(not a great expert in creating one:)...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have this effect in the VSE but you can create it in the 3D view with the image (or movie) that is projected on a subdivided mesh, give 2 shapekeys to this mesh, select the second one:

[image]

In *Edit mode > Mesh > Transform > Randomize*:

[image]

Tweak the parameters in the *Operator Box*, scale and move the mesh if you want:

[image]

Play with the *Value* of the second shapekey:

[image]

Comment: Hi @moonboots As before, thank you very much for your help and your detailed explanation.
Even though it lacks the transition vse part, I still accept it as a solution because it is the key part of the effect.
To anyone who wants to know how to create a custom transition from the animation,
I managed to find a video that explains how to use the animation as a custom effect in the VSE:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0zQ4lfP-EE&ab_channel=Micha%C5%82Chabowski