# Creating crumpled paper in blender

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create crumpled paper in Blender. For that purpose I’ve watched a few tutorials on YouTube. It turns out that in most tutorials the same method is used:  a plane object is placed inside a UV sphere, and Cloth (Leather) and Collision modifiers are used.
Example of [tutorial](https://youtu.be/j5GFtJPvQXo?si=yMmtwUbRmdfdrvHc) (I've chosen the shortest one)

I’ve tried to use the same method. The tutorial helps to create an animation of a paper being crumpled and a convincing lump of paper by the end of animation. But I need to achieve resemblance with this reference.
[image: crumpled paper reference]

The problem is that using method from the tutorial the Cloth modifier bends the object way too soft, whereas crumpled paper has more straight and sharp folds.
Does anyone know the better way to create such a thing?
This is what i got so far

[image: blender screenshot 1]
[image: blender screenshot 2]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/295371/how-to-create-this-crumpled-paper-transition-for-use-in-vse https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77649/crumpled-paper-cycles-texture